# Unable to connect Objection/Knex to Heroku Postgres

Tags: knex.js, heroku-postgres, objection.js

I am running an express node app with objection.js which uses knex on Heroku. Whenever I make a request to an endpoint that makes a database connection, I get the following error.

What does the error invalid_authorization_specification (code 28000) even mean?

Any advice here would be appreciated

```html
{
    "name": "DBError",
    "nativeError": {
        "length": 164,
        "name": "error",
        "severity": "FATAL",
        "code": "28000",
        "file": "auth.c",
        "line": "496",
        "routine": "ClientAuthentication"
    },
    "client": "postgres"
}
```

My knexfile contains the following. I've tried using `connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL` as well, still no dice.

```html
const db_url = process.env.DATABASE_URL
var db_url_groups = db_url.match(/^.*\/\/(.*):(.*)@(.*):.*\/(.*)$/)
var dbUser = db_url_groups[1]
var dbPw = db_url_groups[2]
var dbHost = db_url_groups[3]
var db = db_url_groups[4]
  
module.exports = {
 development: {
     client: 'pg',
     useNullAsDefault: true,
     connection: {
       host : 'db',
       user : 'test',
       password : 'test',
       database : 'local_db'
     }
 },
 production: {
   client: 'pg',
   useNullAsDefault: true,
   connection: {
     host : `${dbHost}`,
     user : `${dbUser}`,
     password : `${dbPw}`,
     database : `${db}`
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had something to do with SSL. Within the connection property, I needed to add an ssl property with the following:

ssl: {
require: false,
rejectUnauthorized: false
}